# Why does $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left\| {T{x_n} - \lambda {x_n}} \right\| = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in B(X)$ and $\lambda  \in \sigma (T)$, why is there a sequence like $\left\{ {{x_n}} \right\}$  in $X$ with $\left\| {{x_n}} \right\| = 1$ such that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left\| {T{x_n} - \lambda {x_n}} \right\| = 0$?

Comment: How far did you get based on the definition of spectrum of $T$?

Comment: @Siminore : Your problem is not a duplicate. This problem is different; in fact the statement in this problem is false.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is false. For example, consider the unilateral shift $S$ on $\ell^{2}$ defined by
$$
    (x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots) \mapsto (0,x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)
$$
Then $\|Sx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in\ell^{2}$, and $0\in\sigma(S)$ because the range of $S$ is of co-dimension $1$ in $\ell^{2}$. However, if $\{ x_n \}$ is a sequence of unit vectors, then $\|(S-0I)x_n\|=\|Sx_n\|=\|x_n\|=1$.